# vb.net - Multiple dialog forms push Main form behind other apps

Tags: vb.net

We have a VB.Net Application with a Main form that should always be visible. However, we want to be able to display a succession of two dialog windows where we can close the first dialog as the second one appears. However, when doing that, the Main form gets sent behind whatever other applications are open and does not re-appear until the second dialog window closes.

We can correct this issue by keeping the first dialog window open behind the second one, but it’s not ideal. What are we doing incorrectly?

Comment: When you're showing the dialogs, are you setting the parent property appropriately? I.e. ShowDialog(mainForm)

Comment: When we show the dialog, we would use something like: frmWindow.ShowDialog() - we're not specifying an owner. It sounds like you're telling me that we should.

Comment: Just to follow-up, when I changed the ShowDialog to include the Main form as the owner, ti didn't make any difference. On the second dialog, the Main form still disappears.

Comment: Are you able to show some code to help us? Have you tried doing dialog1.owner = mainform? Also there is the TopMost property that will keep the form from being sent back. However, it makes your form stay on top of all applications all the time. Unless the user can minimize your form, it's not very user friendly.

Comment: Your comment was helpful. If I add dialog2.owner = mainform in the form load event of the second dialog, then the main form stays on top throughout. There's a slight flicker which indicates that the main form is going to the back and coming to the front very quickly - but that's preferable to the current behavior. Any way I can attribute the answer to you?

Comment: I'll add an answer. Glad you were able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dialog1.owner = mainform`